# The following packages have unmet dependencies when installing mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install mongodb
when executing `sudo apt install mongodb-org`
I get this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm new to linux, what should I do?

context: when running `sudo apt install libssl1.1`

I get
`E: Package 'libssl1.1' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution to install libssl1.1 is to run this

`sudo -i`

`wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

Comment: Make sure that your system can still run `sudo apt upgrade` without any issues. Otherwise this may only be a temporary solution if you still have held broken packages.